# Radius of curvature of a particle with respect to another

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, curvature

A question requires you to find the radius of curvature of a particle with respect to another at a specific instant; the position vectors of both particles(varying with time) are also provided.

The question's done by finding the centripetal acceleration and plugging it into $a_c=\frac{V^2}{R}$.

Why do you have to do any of that? However they may be moving, isn't the radius of curvature of a particle with respect to another... simply the distance between them?

Comment: This might just be a question based on computation. IDK if there is any meaning to radius of curvature of one object with respect to another, one meaning it could have is radius of curvature of object 1 considering object 2 as center of the circle

Comment: Radius of curvature is the radius of a circle that lies tangent to a trajectory at a given point, since some amount of non straightline motion is required for a finite radius of curvature, there has to be some nonzero acceleration of the particle perpendicular to it's motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Isn't the radius of curvature of a particle with respect to another... simply the distance between them?**
No, although it sounds intuitive that it should be.  But even for a single body orbiting around a much larger mass it is not, as a very eccentric orbit illustrates.

Below is a picture of two particles rotating around each other ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem)), and it is clear that by comparing them, that the radius of curvature is not simply the distance between them, and is more about the eccentricity of the orbits.  *That is, the radius of curvature would only equal a distance if there were a distance that stayed constant (thus creating a circle)*, but there is no such distance in this problem.  If they were moving in a perfect circle, or if you could say in a relative sense that they were moving at constant distance from each other, then the radius of curvature would be a distance, but neither of these is generally the case.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is it defined as? The maximum distance?

Comment: @HarryHolmes: It's only the distance in the case of a circular orbit. More generally, one object traces out a curve and the radius of curvature at any point is the radius of the circle which best approximates the curves. Because circles are simple, there are many ways to calculate this depending on how the curves are parameterized. but there's no simple relationship between the distance, maximum distance, etc. Eg: consider a super elongated and eccentric elliptical orbit, that's almost a line, then radius of curvature goes from very small at the ends to very large in the middle.

Comment: That makes sense for one particle, that the infinitesimal arc it traces describes a circle of some varying radius, and that the radius of curvature in that case is that radius. But here, there're two particles, and it's *their* relative radius of curvature that's required. How is this one also that varying circle radius? Is it the vector obtained by taking the difference of the radius vectors of both particles?

Comment: @HarryHolmes: A single massive particle with an eccentric smaller particle (like a comet around the sun) is a counter example to your claim, as I've stated several times. So this is sufficient to disprove it. If it's not, please tell me why not.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean
; I wasn't claiming anything. Just, how is the radius of curvature of a particle *with respect to another* defined? For your example, just the radius of curvature is the common centre around which they rotate. But what's the *relative*  radius?

Comment: @HarryHolmes: There are only two reasonable ways to look at the radius of curvature in this problem: F1) from an absolute frame (like in the picture above); F2) from a frame fixed to one of the particles. I would say that "radius of curvature of a particle with respect to another" is frame F2. In the case where the particles are dramatically different in mass, like a comet around the sun, or a satellite around the earth, F1 and F2 are the same and the problem is simpler (and answers your bolded question at the top), which is why I keep referring to this as an example.

Comment: @HarryHolmes: But regardless of the system or the frame, the "radius of curvature" is the same idea: you would trace out the path (in the frame), and find the radius of curvature at each instant. If the particle traces a perfect circle in that frame, then the radius of curvature is constant and is the radius of the circle. If the particle doesn't trace a circle, then the radius of curvature varies, and at any instance it is the best fit circle to that point in the trajectory -- and it is not going to equal the distance between the particles (I think not ever, but at least not generally).

Comment: Oh, so you view one particle with respect to the other, and then you take the instantaneous curvature of its path, is that it? And here when you get into the frame of reference of one particle, you're not taking it to be the centre of the path the other one's tracing- it's more like an origin in the new coordinate axes formed in its own frame. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @HarryHolmes: Yes, that's what I mean. The curvature of the trace in F2. Attaching frames is a fairly common procedure too. It's a bit tricky in a case like this when the attached frame is accelerated, but it's still common. (Accelerated frames often introduce pseudo-forces (or, some say, fictional forces). For example, imagine holding a pendulum in an accelerating car, the pendulum will swing to the side. Centrifugal forces are another example of pseudo-forces. Also used in robotics, where every joint creates a new frame.)